# Linux Kickstart stops with dialog about “CD Found”

Tags: linux, kickstart

I'm installing Red Hat in a virtual machine, I'm using a kickstart file from an url, but few moments later the system starts to load, it shows a dialog about "CD Found - To begin testing the CD media..."

The kickstart file looks like this:

```
# Kickstart file automatically generated by anaconda.

url --url=http://rha-server/pub/os/rhel5
reboot


install
cdrom
lang en_US.UTF-8
langsupport --default=en_US.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
keyboard us-acentos
xconfig --card "VESA driver (generic)" --videoram 12288 --hsync 31.5-37.9 --vsync 50-70 --resolution 800x600 --depth 16 --startxonboot  --defaultdesktop gnome
network --device eth0 --bootproto dhcp
rootpw --iscrypted $1$ADLUertwert4DAsC7Hi7nN9S/kvbu.
firewall --disabled
selinux --permissive
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=md5
timezone America/Costa_Rica
bootloader --location=mbr --append="rhgb quiet"
# The following is the partition information you requested
# Note that any partitions you deleted are not expressed
# here so unless you clear all partitions first, this is
# not guaranteed to work
clearpart --all
part /boot --fstype ext3 --size=100
part pv.8 --size=10200
#volgroup LV0 --pesize=32768 pv.8
#logvol / --fstype ext3 --name=root --vgname=LV0 --size=6080
#logvol swap --fstype swap --name=swap --vgname=LV0 --size=4096

%packages
@ admin-tools
@ editors
@ emacs
@ system-tools
@ text-internet
@ gnome-desktop
@ dialup
@ compat-arch-support
@ smb-server
@ base-x
@ web-server
@ printing
@ server-cfg
@ development-tools
@ graphical-internet
system-config-httpd
system-config-samba
system-config-printer
system-config-boot
system-switch-mail
kernel
system-config-printer-gui
system-config-kickstart
system-switch-mail-gnome
e2fsprogs
kernel-devel
grub
lvm2

%post

echo "192.168.0.254  rha-server" >> /etc/hosts

RHA_PUB=http://rha-server/pub
curl $RHA_PUB/rha/yum/rha-rhel.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/rha-rhel.repo
curl $RHA_PUB/rha/yum/rha.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/rha.repo

yum groupinstall -y "Red Hat Academy Student"
```

Is there something wrong?

Thanks!

Dialog image: http://img211.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=261712969_Dialog_122_1128lo.jpg

Comment: What does the `cdrom` in your kickstart file mean?

Comment: Not sure, I took it from the file anaconda-ks.cfg from an installed machine with Red Hat.

Answer (score 1):

The "cdrom" line is telling kickstart to do a CD-ROM based install. Remove it and it should use the URL you gave it for the install.

Comment: I'm having the same result, this is the Dialog: http://img211.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=261712969_Dialog_122_1128lo.jpg

Comment: What command / options are you passing at the linux: prompt, if any? Is this original isntallation media, or kickstart media?

Comment: this is the command I'm passing at the start: linux ks=http://website.com/ks.cfg

I'm testing this in a virtual machine. I created the virtual machine and select the iso installer from my desk.

Comment: That's looking for a kickstart file in directory website.com/ on the CD. You have to specify the protocol - http://website.com/ks.cfg. Since it doesn't find the kickstart file in that directory, it defaults to a CD-based install.

Comment: Thanks. How do I specify the protocol?

Comment: Hmm. I thought I'd added that...  the full URL seems to be masked. Use http-colon-slash-slash-website.com-slash-ks.cfg.

Comment: I did that. Actually it is getting the file, because if I put some wrong url it shows an error.